# Using a Publication List with a triggered send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

There is a similar question out [there](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105603/associating-a-publication-list-to-a-triggered-email-send) that doesn't specifically answer the question I am asking.

I want to know if it is possible to associate a Publication List when sending a triggered send to a data extension. I do not want to select a list for the triggered send as was the answer given in the above question. A data extension better fits my needs, but I do not want unsubscribes to this send to be universal (All Subscribers).

Is there some way to associate a Publication List to a triggered send or perhaps some other way to control the level of Opt-Out on a triggered send via a data extension?

Answer (score 0):

The typical use case for Triggered Sends is transactional (operational) type emails that are sent as one-off email to a specific recipient in response to an action they have performed (ie place an order, request a password reset).  These emails are not the type of emails that recipients unsubscribe from and can be sent using an operational send classification which ignore the unsubscribe status on a subscriber.

When a data extension is specified for a Triggered Send, that data extension will have a row written to it for each triggered email request, sort of like a log. It doesn't send to all of the records in that data extension and doesn't pull existing data from that data extension to be used for send-time personalization.

If you are sending Commercial messages using a Triggered Send, then selecting a list is going to be your best option as it will add the records to that List and use it for subscriber management.  This option can be used along with a data extension for the use case mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Mac, a couple of follow-up questions:<br/>
- What about the use of a Suppression List with a TS? Could that be a psuedo workaround to honor user preferences?<br/>
- Can you elaborate on the use of Lists with Data Extensions?